# How to get the number of apache's HttpClient active connections?

Tags: apache, httpclient

I want to know how to get the active connection number of HttpClient connection pool? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general :- 
netstat -na | more

For a particular IP and port:-

netstat -na | ip:port | more